# How to get user location in android google map

Tags: android, google-maps

i have following code for show user location in my app :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback, LocationListener {
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private Marker userMarker;
    private Marker destinationMarker;
    private Location userLocation;
    private Location destinationLocation;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 101;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    SupportMapFragment supportMapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    supportMapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

}

private void setupLocationManager() {
    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    if (locationManager != null) {
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
                        , Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION}, REQUEST_CODE);
            }
            return;
        }
        if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            onLocationChanged(location);
            locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 4000, 5, this);
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
    this.googleMap = googleMap;
    googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
            destinationLocation = new Location(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            destinationLocation.setLatitude(latLng.latitude);
            destinationLocation.setLongitude(latLng.longitude);
            Polyline line = googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                    .add(new LatLng(userLocation.getLatitude(),
                            userLocation.getLongitude()), new LatLng(destinationLocation.getLatitude(),
                            destinationLocation.getLongitude())).color(Color.BLUE).width(10).geodesic(true));
            destinationMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Destination Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_destination_marker)));
        }
    });
    setupLocationManager();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    if (location != null && googleMap != null) {
        userLocation = location;
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
        if (userMarker != null) {
            userMarker.remove();
        }
        userMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title("Your Location").icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.ic_user_marker)));
        CameraUpdate cameraUpdate = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(latLng, 10);
        googleMap.animateCamera(cameraUpdate);
    }else {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Location is null",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
    super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (grantResults[0] == 0) {
            setupLocationManager();
        }
    }
}
}
```

My manifest permissions :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

I have two problems:

- first : my code don't show user location in real device(app always
  show **Location is null**(toast message in onLocationChanged()) I
  dont know why (solved)
- second : i want to my Polyline shows in roads. I know about
  `isGeodesic()` function but it doesn't show when i use...

Comment: did you gave proper permissions in manifest file. If so check is log weather you are getting lat and long values

Comment: @SunilP check update man

Comment: Ok check in log for lat and long values

Comment: @SunilP check what for lat and long values ? for user location ? and where i have to check ? sry i am beginner...

Comment: Are you testing on a real device that has GPS enabled?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes is enabled. default device's map my location shows as well.

Comment: `location.getLatitude()` `location.getLongitude()` check for this lines you are getting values in log or no.

Comment: @SunilP no value. it seems like doesn't run...

Comment: @SunilP @TimBiegleisen i have `Searching for GPS` on my device's notification. i think it is working but is too low speed...<br/>Any idea?

Comment: @SunilP can you solve my second prob ?

Comment: @TimBiegleisen  can you solve my second prob ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that the "location" is null because in your example the toast can be shown also if "googleMap" is null?

If your "location" is null make sure you have these permissions in your Android Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
```

Then check if your location permission is granted to your application (very important if you are using device with API version 23 or higher but I think you are granting it because you are overriding the "onRequestPermissionsResult" method).

If everything is OK, check is your device location enabled, if it is not - enable it and wait for a location change again.

Comment: yes i test for google map and location for null and google map isn't null.location is null.this line is null: `Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);` i sure i added permissions..

Comment: When using "getLastKnownLocation" you need to have previous location fix obtained from the given provider (in your case GPS) I do not recommend you to use "getLastKnownLocation" because it not always contains location. Instead of this wait for new, fresh location fix. If your GPS signal is low, you may cannot obtain new location. Try using "LocationManager.NETWORK_PRO‌​VIDER" and share the result.

Comment: Yes man thx it works but why gps doesnt work ? hey bro it was my first problem.can you tell me how can i solve second prob ?

Comment: Cannot help you for the second one. Just take a look at the Android API ( Google map integration) but I'm not sure if there is an official documented road snapping for polylines.

Answer (score 2):

Add `googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);` in your onMapReady() which will show user location on google map.

```
 @Override
        public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
            this.googleMap = googleMap;
            final LatLng current_position = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(current_position).title("XY Address").snippet("XY Address");
            googleMap.addMarker(marker);
            googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(current_position, 12));
            googleMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(true);
            googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    }
```

Comment: thx man but i cant handle `googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener()` function with your code... any way ?

Comment: use a custom GPS class to receive lat and long onLocationChanged()